# How to set equal priority_weight to task that depends on another task

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have 8 set of tasks. Each set is a series of task: task1 >> task2 >> task3.
task3 depends on task2, so as task2 depends on task1.

My problem is that task2 never starts until all task1 are finished.
So in order for set1.task2 to start it must run set8.task1 first.

My initial research is something about `priority_weight` that can be included in the default_args for the DAG. I have learned that task1 would have higher priority_weight to its downstream.

Is there a way in such that all priority weights can all be the same. So that set1.task2 can already start regardless of set2,3, etc. since it just depends on set1.task1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `weight_rule` to 'upstream' or 'absolute' should help. This is from the `BaseOperator` docstring:

```
:param weight_rule: weighting method used for the effective total
    priority weight of the task. Options are:
    ``{ downstream | upstream | absolute }`` default is ``downstream``
    When set to ``downstream`` the effective weight of the task is the
    aggregate sum of all downstream descendants. As a result, upstream
    tasks will have higher weight and will be scheduled more aggressively
    when using positive weight values. This is useful when you have
    multiple dag run instances and desire to have all upstream tasks to
    complete for all runs before each dag can continue processing
    downstream tasks. When set to ``upstream`` the effective weight is the
    aggregate sum of all upstream ancestors. This is the opposite where
    downtream tasks have higher weight and will be scheduled more
    aggressively when using positive weight values. This is useful when you
    have multiple dag run instances and prefer to have each dag complete
    before starting upstream tasks of other dags.  When set to
    ``absolute``, the effective weight is the exact ``priority_weight``
    specified without additional weighting. You may want to do this when
    you know exactly what priority weight each task should have.
    Additionally, when set to ``absolute``, there is bonus effect of
    significantly speeding up the task creation process as for very large
    DAGS. Options can be set as string or using the constants defined in
    the static class ``airflow.utils.WeightRule``
```

Link: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L129-L150

Comment: where do you place this argument? in the default args of the DAG?

Comment: Thank you! I set it inside each task. I am not sure if this can be a default argument in the DAG.

Comment: I believe it can, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding any parameter for a DAG is applied to all the tasks defined under that DAG. You can pass `weight_rule` in a default_args while instantiating the DAG.

For Eg:

```
with DAG(
    "dag_1",
    schedule_interval="@daily", 
    catchup=False,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 9, 10),
    default_args={
        "priority_weight": 5,
        "pool": "testing_pool",
        "weight_rule": "absolute",
    },
) as dag:
```